# Designing a destination prediction model based on historical trips

Tags: classification

I am working on a dataset with more than 100,000 users who ask for ride in Uber-like services.
The features are the following: user.id ,trip-origin-lat-long,trip-destination-lat-long, request timestamp.

I want to make a model that predicts destination of user based on his/her trip history.

I think it is a classification problem.
so, I have 2 questions:

1-which kind of classification algorithm should I use?
2-should I train a model for every single user or should I train a model for all users based using their user id as a feature?